# Is the set of all elements above some fixed element a lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a lattice and $x\in L$ a fixed element. Consider $L':=\{y\in L\mid x \leq y\}$.

> Is $L'$ a lattice?

If $a,b\in L'$, then $x\leq a \leq a\lor b\in L'$, so I guess the join in $L'$ is just the join in $L$.

But I'm not sure whether $L'$ has a meet operation. Let again $a, b\in L'$. Then the meet of $a, b\in L$ is an element $a\land b\in L$ such that $a\land b\leq a$ and $a\land b\leq b$. I don't see whether I conclude from this that $a\land b$ are in $L'$. But $a\land b\in L'$ should be true if the implication
$$(x\leq a) \,\&\, (x\leq b)\implies (x\leq a\land b)$$
holds in a lattice, because then by definition of $L'$ we have $a\land b\in L'$.

> Does this implication hold in any lattice?

A further question is:

> If $L$ is a complete lattice, is $L'$ a complete lattice?

Comment: For the first question note that $x\le a$ if and only if $x=x\land a$, so if $x\le a$ and $x\le b$, then $x\land (a\land b)=(x\land a)\land b=x\land b=x$, and therefore $x\le a\land b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L'$ is a lattice since $x \leq a$ and $x \leq b$ implies that $x \leq a \wedge b$ (which is one of your questions).

Again, if $L$ is complete, and $A \subseteq L'$, then $x \leq \bigwedge A$, by the same reason.
So $L'$ will be complete too (having $x$ as its bottom element).